# android and webos no content scaling?

Tags: iphone, android, css, webos

I am currently building a website optimized for mobile devices.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;"/>
```

I have a dynamic javascript grid and i want no scaling on mobile devices.

The line above works perfectly on the iphone, however I think it does not work on android or webos. How can I set a NO-SCALE mode for those mobile devices as well. So there is no pinch & zoom and the device-width is the 100% browser-width?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/targeting.html#Metadata, the "user-scalable" property needs to be set to "no", not 0. So:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no;"/>
```

**EDIT**: A bit more info near the bottom of the page at [Safari Reference Library - Supported Meta Tags](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html):

> **user-scalable**
>   Determines whether or not the user can
>   zoom in and out—whether or not the
>   user can change the scale of the
>   viewport. Set to `yes` to allow scaling
>   and `no` to disallow scaling. The
>   default is `yes`.
>
> Setting `user-scalable` to `no` also
>   prevents a webpage from scrolling when
>   entering text in an input field.
>
> Available in iOS 1.0 and later.